# FluentNHibernate Formula Mapping C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, substring

Is there a way to declare a map passing a Formula which will run just for a specific statement *(`SELECT` in my case)*?

The problem is that I have something like

```
Map(x => x.Id).Formula("SUBSTRING(id, 0, 2)");
```

But it's causing errors when I try to run an insert for this specific entity, because it's using the `Formula` for the insert statement as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have to make such column readonly

```
Map(x => x.Id)
    .Formula("SUBSTRING(id, 0, 2)")
    .ReadOnly();
```

or more like original **`insert="false" udpate="false"`**

```
Map(x => x.Id)
    .Formula("SUBSTRING(id, 0, 2)")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
```

Comment: I didn't work for us, 'cause we have to be able to use that column for insert statements as well (this is not a identity field)

Comment: Formula will **never** be insertable. It is just a read column. I would suggest... Map it twice. Once for just Insert... as a column ("id")... this will be inserted during entity creation. Later you can use formula for reading. That should work. But as I said "Formula itself will **NEVER be insertable**"